# Gray out entire map except a portion in Google maps iOS

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am using Google maps in iOS using iOS SDK, letting users mark an area using few markers, creating a polygon.

I want to highlight that area and gray out the rest of the map, something like this:

[image]

Is this possible somehow?

Answer (score 0):

You have to draw your own UIImage where you create the gray area, clear area, and polygon borders.  After that add it as an overlay tile using GMSGroundOverlay.  This will fix it in place for when the user scrolls.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/overlays

This is similar to how radar overlays are drawn for weather apps.

Answer (score -1):

I would approach this problem using several steps.

1) collect your points from the user that will define your polygon.

2) send the collection of points to your server.(ajax post)

3) server side, dynamically create a grey image with a transparent hole in it that is your polygon.

4) store image on server, send back response with info telling browser how to retrieve it(url,id,whatever).

5) using javascript + google maps api, apply an overlay referencing your newly created image.

each step may have its challenges but the problem becomes manageable if you focus on the different steps.

1) and 2) will involve using javascript, capturing 'clicks' and having feedback to the user in the form of a line or something on the map.  Once finished, the server call can be initiated by the user or by your programming.

3) I would use python with an image library(skimage, etc.) and a mapping library (gdal). Making an image is not hard but combining it with GIS and getting the right projection, etc. will take some fiddling.

4) shouldn't be a problem once you've got that far.

5) using zimmryan's comment about creating a ground overlay could be helpful for this step.

good luck!